# Why releasing a save point with no outer transaction does not save changes?

Tags: sqlite

According to the SQLite3-documentation releasing top-level save point, not being wrapped with an outer transaction, commits its changes. But in fact it doesn't happen. What can be wrong?

**UPDATE**:

I figured out that happens after rollback of a previous save point:

```c
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  sqlite3* db;
  if (sqlite3_open("/Users/ababo/Desktop/test.sqlite3", &db) != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create db: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return 1;
  }

  const char* sql = "SAVEPOINT sp";
  if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create savepoint: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return 1;
  }

  sql = "ROLLBACK TO sp";
  if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to rollback savepoint: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return 1;
  }

  sql = "SAVEPOINT sp";
  if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create savepoint again: %s\n",
            sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return 1;
  }

  sql = "CREATE table t(f int)";
  if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create table: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return 1;
  }

  sql = "RELEASE sp";
  if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to release savepoint: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

As far as I understand, the problem is that `RELEASE sp` does not remove the save point from transaction stack, so the next `SAVEPOINT sp` pushes a next save point. Is there a way to remove the save point while rolling it back?

Comment: There's no way to answer that without an [mcve].

Comment: Added a code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `RELEASE` command clears the transaction stack of the 2nd `sp` savepoint. However, the outer (first) savepoint is still on the transaction stack, because the `ROLLBACK TO` command *does not* clear the targeted savepoint. If you had used `ROLLBACK` (without a `TO` clause), then the first savepoint would be cleared.

See the SQLite [docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_savepoint.html) for further details.

Comment: But in case of an outer transaction it will roll it back, which is not wanted. I just want to rollback the save point continuing the outer transaction in that case. But in case if it's absent, I would like to rollback the save point. I'll explain simpler. I need to a way to implement a compound routine in transactional manner whether it's wrapped with transaction or not.

Comment: In other words I probably need full-fledged nested transactions which are not supported.

Comment: Your question asks how and why this is happening. If you wanted to know "How do I do X?", you should have asked that question.

Comment: Right question is a half of the answer, and I've just come to it.